# Expect TCP to fail when the remote endpoint is not connected C#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

using .net sockets. I am trying to determine whether the socket is connected or not.
there for I expect the send operation to fail if the remote endpoint is not connected.
practically I do not get an exception on the send but the send passes successfully only after a while the send will fail.
is there any explanation for this?
what else can i do in order to get the connection state?

my code is very simple
based on this
 `

```
Int32 port = 13000;
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

// Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);         

// Get a client stream for reading and writing.
```

//  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

```
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

// Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);         

// Receive the TcpServer.response.

// Buffer to store the response bytes.
data = new Byte[256];

// String to store the response ASCII representation.
String responseData = String.Empty;

// Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);         

// Close everything.
client.Close();    `
```

Comment: Can you show your code? TCP is a reliable protocol, it will try to send data until a timeout. I guess you are after tweaking a timeout property.

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/9707314/128217

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'connection state' in TCP. The only reliable way to detect a broken connection is to try to write to it repeatedly: eventually a broken connection will cause ECONNRESET or whatever that maps to in your programming language. You should also use a read timeout when reading, of some value like double the expected latency of the longest request, and treat that as a broken connection or at least a broken transaction as well, but this is problematic if transaction latencies vary wildly.